# Laravel middleware to augment route model binding for security

Tags: laravel, ioc-container, middleware

Can anyone think of a slick way to middleware or ioc the 'if' statement so that we can use route-model-binding a bit more securely?

```
Route::get('/channel-groups/{channelGroup}/channels/{channel}', [
    'as'   => 'channel-groups',
    'uses' => function(\App\Distribution\UserConfigurations\ChannelGroup $channelGroup, \App\Distribution\UserConfigurations\Channel $channel){

        //@todo: middleware
        if(!$channelGroup->Channels->contains($channel)){
            return abort(401, 'Unauthorized');
        }

        return $channel;
    }
]);
```

Comment: this might help! https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6118